# Can we write `when`/`then` inside if condition in spock test

Tags: java, groovy, spock, specifications

Can we write `when`/`then` inside if condition in spock test? Code looks like this. Here i am trying to control the calling of when and then.

```
def testMethod(){
    given:
        if(some Condition) {
            when:
                eventOne Occurred
            then:
                assertion based on eventOne
        } else if (some Condition) {
            when:
                eventTwo Occurred
            then:
                assertion based on eventTwo
        } else {
            when:
                eventThree Occurred
            then:
                assertion based on eventThree
        }
    where:
        iteration here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of this? The `given-when-then` approach was designed to make automated tests easier to understand. The example you shown makes reading and understanding your test hard. And I would even bet it wont compile.

Try keeping your tests simple. `where` is used for providing parameters to your test (parameterized test), e.g.

```
@Unroll    
def "should return #result for parameters(#a,#b)"() {

    when:
        def result = someObject.someMethod(a, b)

    then:
        result == expected

    where:
        a           | b             || expected
        null        | null          || false
        ""          | ""            || false
        "test"      | "foo"         || true
}
```

The main purpose here is to keep understanding the test logic as simple as possible. If you want to test different combination then you might create separate test method.

Answer (score 1):

From the Spock perspective I can't find any restrictions for your specific example. From the readability perspective I don't think it is the best way to use Spock - I agree with answer above.

But please be aware of the following limitation of the Spock labels (from [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/spock_primer.html)):

> A feature method must have at least one explicit (i.e. labelled) block
>   - in fact, the presence of an explicit block is what makes a method a feature method. Blocks divide a method into distinct sections, and
>   **cannot be nested**.

So logically you can think of your example as:

1. given - is a set-up phase;
2. when-then from the first condition;
3. when-then from the second condition;
4. when-then from the third condition;
5. where - describes the data supplies;